# LibGdx android game rendering bug

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi we are close to releasing a new android game. We are using LibGdx. Having a problem where a random line is drawn across the screen on different devices. (Doesn't always happen). We have made sure all of our sprites in the sprite sheet have adequate empty space around it. Here is a screen shot of the issue.
[image: Crop Defence]

Comment: Without knowing more about how you render your screen it's next to impossible to answer this with any certainty. What can you tell us about the rendering? Are you using a `TiledMap`, are drawing sprites directly, are the sprites individual textures or texture regions. The problem only seems to affect the background, what difference is there between how you render the background and the foreground?

Comment: Yeah i really should have added that! We load in a sprite sheet and then get textures regions from that and render them directly. No TiledMap. Also the background colour is just set using the glClearColour.

Comment: It only seems to happen on the more 'thinner and longer' screen phones? Like the samsung S8 or S7. But on pixel devices it seems to be fine? The issue used to occur when the devices virtual android buttons were showing. (Multitasking home and back). When I hid them the line got removed. Do you think it has something to do with the graphics having to strech to fit on the longer screens?

Comment: @AaronNebbs You can edit your question to add more information. 
For example, is the horizontal line of the same color as you're using to clear the screen with the `glClearColor`? By background I mean the brown and blue parts in your image, is that one texture region or several? How are you placing them on screen (it could be a rounding issue on the y-axis). Try to add some code that shows us the core parts of your render method.

Comment: You said you have empty space around your sprites, but what you actually want is color bleeding.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I want colour bleeding? When I didn't have the padding we got artefacts around the sprites.

Comment: @bornander The line is in the colour of the glClearColor. The bottom farm land are rendered as individual sprites next to each other. It is using a rect to hold the locations, calling getY() actually returns a float. Do you think this could be the issue?

Comment: Color bleeding means you have padding, but the padding has the same color as the adjacent pixels of the sprite. There's an option for it the LibGDX texture packer.

Comment: @AaronNebbs I'd say it's either from lack of padding of the regions in the spritesheet (the padding should be the same color as the pixel being padded like Tenfour04 says), or it's because of rounding errors when calculating the y-pos. One way to find out which one it is could be to change the background color of your spritesheet to magenta instead of transparent and see if the line shows up as magenta or the glClearColor. If it is magenta the problem is padding.